# Spyder installation without Anaconda

Tags: python, spyder

I already have Python 3.6 (32-bit) on Windows 7. Is there a way to install Spyder without downloading Anaconda, WinPython, etc. ?

Comment: pip install spyder

Comment: yes sure you can, just follow : https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html
or download here : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyder

Comment: you could also install using miniconda to avoid extra stuff

Answer (score 20):

You need to run the following commands in order to install and run the `Spyder3` without anaconda:

```
 1. python -m pip install pyqt5
 2. python -m pip install spyder
 3. python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
 4. spyder (to launch spyder)
```

Package in point 3 also needs to be installed explicitly.

Answer (score 13):

You need to run in a system terminal (`cmd.exe`) these commands

```
pip install spyder
pip install pyqt5
```

However, please be aware that this kind of installation is not recommended for beginners, but only for very knowledgeable programmers, because if errors appear during the installation, you need to know very well all Spyder dependencies to solve them.

Comment: OK. I've installed it and how can I launch it? Simply typing 'spyder' in cmd doesn't work and I don't see any .exe files. I have a spyder folder in Lib/site-packages.

Comment: You need to type `spyder3` instead of `spyder`

Comment: Nothing lanuches when typing spyder3, yet no errors. When I try to reinstall I just get a bunch of "requirement already satisfied" messages.

Comment: spyder3.exe is in 'scripts' folders and doesn't react when clicked

Comment: You can try to run `spyder3 --reset` and try again.

Comment: I executed your solution as you told above. But, when I'm typing spyder3 in CMD, an initialization image of Spyder are appeared. But, Spyder cannot be launched. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's actually not that easy. I just want to install a package as I use to do with Anaconda, just type pip install package_name. But now it's not possible because I installed Spyder5 without anaconda and I just can't find how or where to use pip. There is no path to python to use in cmd because it seems that only python I have is the one 'inside' syper 5. Then how I'm supposed to install a package under this configuration??

Comment: @MoisésBriseñoEstrello, did you use our Windows or Mac installer to install Spyder?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba windows x64 installer.

Comment: Then please read our [FAQ](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) on how to use other packages than come with it.

Answer (score 2):

**Installation Spyder**
Install Spyder and its other dependencies, run `pip install spyder`. You may need to install a Qt binding (PyQt5) separately with pip if running under Python 2

**Launch Spyder**
To launch Sypder go to your Python installation directory. in my case C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Scripts

Launch spyder3.exe

Answer (score 2):

They’ve recently provided stand-alone installers for Mac & Windows, including a “lite” version.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve struggled a lot on this on Windows.
This is what I did and worked clean (without Python, Anaconda or Spyder allready installed - if any allready installed uninstalit).
The following worked today but, I'll think, it will be ok in the near future too.

1. Install PYTHON exe
   https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.10/python-3.9.10-amd64.exe
2. Install SPYDER exe
   https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/latest/download/Spyder_64bit_full.exe
3. In Spyder, change the Interpreter:

Tools -> Preferences -> Use the following Python interpreter:
(myne is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe)

Hit Apply, hit OK.

4. Close and open Spyder

You will receive a message like this:

*The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
doesn't have the spyder kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= **2.2.1** and < 2.3.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.
You can install it by activating your environment (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
conda install spyder kernels=2.2
or
pip install spyder kernels==2.2.*

Remember  this from above: *(**>= 2.2.1** and < 2.3.0)*

5. Close Spyder and do in CMD:

pip install spyder-kernels==**2.2.1**

6. Some test:

In Spyder:

```
import pandas as pd
```

It’s OK error:
*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'*

In CMD:
pip install pandas

After that, in Spyder:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
1.4.1
```

If no errors occurs and some version appears, than Python and Spyder work together.
End of test.

Answer (score -3):

According to the [Sypder-Docs](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html), After installing the Python, run the following command:

```
pip install PyQt5 Qtconsole Rope Pyflakes Sphinx Pygments Pylint Pycodestyle Psutil Nbconvert Qtawesome Pickleshare PyZMQ QtPy Chardet Numpydoc Cloudpickle PyQtWebEngine spyder
```

(Do not use "3" in front of spyder in pip install). After that, run it by typing in spyder3 in command window (Here "3" is required)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no need to install all our dependencies explicitly. You simply need to run `pip install spyder`.

Comment: @CarlosCordobaOn macOS we just run `pip install spyder`. If I run the command in a venv it will only install for that venv? Or is this a proper full user install of Spyder? Also, How would I point Spyder to my pyenv shims python? Lastly, if I give in and just install Anaconda so I can use Spyder, will the new Anaconda path break any current pyenv python paths? Ideally, I would like to maintain my current pyenv python 3.8 set up and just install Anaconda on top and run with both. As I understand it, installing Anaconda should not affect my current set up right? Thanks!