# Installing Pipetorch in Spyder 5.3 Python 3.8.10

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, spyder

I have tried many times to install Pipetorch in Spyder 5.3 with Python 3.8.10, but it failed.

I have tried as well conda as pip commands, but it does not work. If I use %pip I get this:

`Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages. C:\Users\szewa\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\python.exe: No module named pip`

If I use conda I get this:

```
`ValueError: The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  Please use ``%pip install instead.`
```

Can someone help me? I can find nothing on internet that works...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the differences between pip and conda. Anyhow, your Python installation is messed up now and only a restart will help now.

1. The easiest way to use Python together with the Spyder IDE is to install Anaconda and learn some conda basics: [Getting started with conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html).
2. If you really want to install Spyder with standard Python, follow the recipe from [Spyder installation without Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587226/spyder-installation-without-anaconda), but it seems to be tricky.